# Sharing Mutable Data Between Threads in Rust

Tags: multithreading, rust

I know there are hundreds of questions just like this one, but i'm having trouble wrapping my head around how to do the thing I'm trying to do.

I want an http server that accepts and processes events. On receiving/processing an event, i want the `EventManager` to send an update to an `ApplicationMonitor` that is tracking how many events have been accepted/processed. The `ApplicationMonitor` would also (eventually) handle things like tracking number of concurrent connections, but in this example I just want my `EventManager` to send an `Inc('event_accepted')` update to my `ApplicationMonitor`.

To be useful, I need the `ApplicationMonitor` to be able to return a snapshot of the stats when the requested through a `/stats` route.

[image]

So I have an `ApplicationMonitor` which spawns a thread and listens on a channel for incoming `Stat` events. When it receives a `Stat` event it updates the stats HashMap. The stats hashmap must be mutable within both `ApplicationMonitor` as well as the spawned thread.

```
use std::sync::mpsc;
use std::sync::mpsc::Sender;
use std::thread;
use std::thread::JoinHandle;
use std::collections::HashMap;

pub enum Stat {
    Inc(&'static str),
    Dec(&'static str),
    Set(&'static str, i32)
}

pub struct ApplicationMonitor {
    pub tx: Sender<Stat>,
    pub join_handle: JoinHandle<()>
}

impl ApplicationMonitor {
    pub fn new() -> ApplicationMonitor {
        let (tx, rx) = mpsc::channel::<Stat>();

        let mut stats: HashMap<&'static str, i32> = HashMap::new();

        let join_handle = thread::spawn(move || {
            for stat in rx.recv() {
                match stat {
                    Stat::Inc(nm) => {
                        let current_val = stats.entry(nm).or_insert(0);
                        stats.insert(nm, *current_val + 1);
                    },
                    Stat::Dec(nm) => {
                        let current_val = stats.entry(nm).or_insert(0);
                        stats.insert(nm, *current_val - 1);
                    },
                    Stat::Set(nm, val) => {
                        stats.insert(nm, val);
                    }
                }
            }
        });

        let am = ApplicationMonitor {
            tx,
            join_handle
        };

        am
    }

    pub fn get_snapshot(&self) -> HashMap<&'static str, i32> {
        self.stats.clone()
    }
}
```

Because `rx` cannot be cloned, I must `move` the references into the closure. When I do this, I am no longer able to access `stats` outside of the thread.

I thought maybe I needed a second channel so the thread could communicate it's internals back out, but this doesn't work as i would need another thread to listen for that in a non-blocking way.

Is this where I'd use `Arc`?

How can I have `stats` live inside and out of the thread context?

Answer (score 3):

Yes, this is a place where you'd wrap your `stats` in an `Arc` so that you can have multiple references to it from different threads. But just wrapping in an `Arc` will only give you a read-only view of the `HashMap` - if you need to be able to modify it, you'll also need to wrap it in something which guarantees that only one thing can modify it at a time. So you'll probably end up with either an `Arc<Mutex<HashMap<&'static str, i32>>>` or a `Arc<RwLock<HashMap<&'static str, i32>>>`.

Alternatively, if you're just changing the values, and not adding or removing values, you could potentially use an `Arc<HashMap<&static str, AtomicU32>>`, which would allow you to read and modify different values in parallel without needing to take out a `Map`-wide lock, but `Atomic`s can be a little more fiddly to understand and use correctly than locks.